# Is Request.IsAjaxRequest() broken in the MVC RC1 refresh?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

This MVC stuff is fun but every step along the way theres another little hurdle.

I'm just using [Request.IsAjaxRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289108/is-there-a-request-ismvcajaxrequest-equivalent-for-jquery/498658#498658) for the first time today in conjunction with Microsoft's AJAX library. I am NOT yet using jQuery (I had to mention that since I just hyperlinked to a question about jQuery!).

Unfortunately I installed [RC1 refresh](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/30/aspnetmvc-refresh.aspx) BEFORE I tested this code.

I am using `Ajax.BeginForm`.

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Contact", "AboutUs", new AjaxOptions()
      {
          OnBegin = "submitComments_begin",
          OnSuccess = "submitComments_success",
          OnFailure = "submitComments_failure",
          OnComplete = "submitComments_complete",
          LoadingElementId = "submitting"

      }, new { id="fooForm" }))
```

When my controller action executes these are my headers :

> Connection Pragma, Content-Length,
>   Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding,
>   Accept-Language, Host, Referer,
>   User-Agent, UA-CPU

In addition the FORM contains this Param

```
Request["__MVCASYNCPOST"] = "true"
```

And the end effect is that this returns false!

```
Request.IsAjaxRequest()
```

I get the issue with Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Please tell me if I'm doin something silly - or if something just broke.

**Final thought:** Hmm - perhaps I need a new futures DLL. I'll update if that turns out to be the issue

Comment: btw it is DEFINITELY running through ajax - (i dont have JS disabled for instance). i know this because my onComplete handler executes and the page vertical scrollbar doesn't reset

Comment: I have same problem, but it didnt fix when i updated acripts. any thoughts?

Comment: @zsharp - are you using Fiddler? if not get it. look at the HTTP request being sent by the AJAX call. verify that it does NOT contain __MVCASYNCPOST as a parameter. clear your cache if still having issues. you replaced this file right? MicrosoftMvcAjax.js. mine is 5,287 bytes long

Comment: @zsharp - also make sure that if you're using the debug version that you copied over the debug version of MicrosoftMvcAjax.js too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Phil for [telling me I had to update the .js file](http://www.haacked.com/archive/2009/01/30/aspnetmvc-refresh.aspx) MicrosoftMvcAjax.js. Even though it didn't actually tell me in the release notes that I need to update them.

Phil: If you want the points for the correct answer you have 2 days until i can accept my own answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure if this is a bug or not - can anyone confirm?? Remember I'm talking about the new RC1 Refresh, not the original RC1.

In the event that it IS a bug (and I'm hoping i'm just doing something careless) then this is my temporary solution for now:

**Extension method on HttpRequestBase :**

```
public static bool IsAjaxRequest2(this HttpRequestBase request)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(
                   request.Params["__MVCASYNCPOST"] as string);
        }
```

Then I just use `Request.IsAjaxRequest2()` and I'll search and replace later when its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't show in the snippet you have posted, but you most likely have form /form tags. These are interfering with the Ajax.BeginForm which generates the form tags as well. Once you remove the outer form tags, the Request.IsAjaxRequest will return true.

Comment: that might be a problem elsewhere, but in this case it was the MicrosoftMvcAjax.js that needed updating. i've switched to jQuery now anyway